# How was De Saussure's Langue and Parole different from Chomsky's Competence and Performance?

Tags: theoretical-linguistics, chomsky

Ferdinan De Sassure has proposed Langue and Parole long before Chomsky proposed his Competence and Performance system of linguistic knowledge? I know that they are different but how?

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is probably that Chomsky's *competence* is a purely individual notion: it's the linguistic knowledge of a single speaker-hearer. Saussure's *langue*, by contrast, is not a property of any one individual but exists only at the level of society.